# Windows Phone 8 Control Orientation

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm working on a custom Control for Windows Phone 8. The control includes a `VideoBrush` that I need to rotate to keep consistent with the outside page as the page rotates. I assumed the `Control` class would have an `OnOrientationChanged` event just like `PhoneApplicationPage` does, but it doesn't.

Is there anyway of detecting the orientation of the containing page? I could add a method to the control to allow rotating the video feed. The developer using the control would then be able to update the control's orientation on the page's `OrientationChanged` event but that seems clunky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the OrientationChanged event of the PhoneApplicationFrame, which is available via App.RootFrame.

If you do need the page, you can navigate up the VisualTree to find the containing page with VisualTreeHelper.GetParent, and hook the orientation changed event yourself.

Comment: I ended up navigating the VisualTree to find the page. I was worried that if I used the frame, the video would rotate even when rotation of the page was disabled.